# Get Child item from xml document

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML document and i am trying to find a way to be able to pass a host name and then get the following host-ip entry for that hostname.

Below is the following sample xml document:

```
<ReportHost name="WebServerA.internal">
<HostProperties>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-5">10.1.1.5</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-4">10.3.4.2</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-3">10.5.10.25</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-2">10.54.22.122</tag>
<tag name="cpe-1">cpe:/a:microsoft:iis:8.5</tag>
<tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-1">10.10.10.54</tag>
<tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">14</tag>
<tag name="cpe-0">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:r2</tag>
<tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag>
<tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard</tag>
<tag name="LastUnauthenticatedResults">1545398521</tag>
<tag name="Credentialed_Scan">false</tag>
<tag name="policy-used">Basic Network Scan</tag>
<tag name="os">windows</tag>
<tag name="mac-address">00:10:36:A5:3B:AA</tag>
<tag name="host-fqdn">WebServerA.internal</tag>
<tag name="host-rdns">WebServerA.internal</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-0">10.1.5.12</tag>
<tag name="HOST_END">Fri Dec 21 08:22:01 2018</tag>
<tag name="netbios-name">WEBSERVERA</tag>
<tag name="host-ip">10.1.5.33</tag>
<tag name="HOST_START">Fri Dec 21 08:16:28 2018</tag>
</HostProperties>
</ReportHost>

for host in root.iter('HostProperties'):
    for child in host:
        # If i print attrib from loop above i only see name:value pairs,  but i can't seem to get the value for host-ip
        print(child.attrib.get('name:host-ip')) *** THIS DOESN'T WORK ***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ...
  <tag name="netbios-name">WEBSERVERA</tag>
  <tag name="host-ip">10.1.5.33</tag>
  <tag name="HOST_START">Fri Dec 21 08:16:28 2018</tag>
</HostProperties>
```

when looping through the `HostProperties` you will be getting all the `<tag>` elements as children. the attrib are the elements attributes(name) and text will get you the value defined inside the tag.

```
for child in host:
    print( child.name , child.attrib.name , child.text )

>> ... 
>> tag netbios-name WEBSERVERA
>> tag host-ip 10.1.5.33
>> tag HOST_START Fri Dec 21 08:16:28 2018
```

---

*update*

parsing(sax) and a DOM aren't always the same thing. that being said if you want to correlate two things in a document you will need to model that document internally some how.

```
hosts = {} 
...
for child in host: 
   hosts[child.attrib.name] = child.text
print("{} : {}".format(hosts['netbios-name'],hosts['host-ip']))


>> WEBSERVERA : 10.1.5.33
```

If there are multiple hostproperties (only one shown) you could create a map that is like `{'WEBSERVERA':{'host-ip':...`

That being said the structure of your xml has a lot to be desired. If you can change the schema it would aid in how you can parse it. For instance if the `name` field is important in the hostproperties object it should be an attribute of the hostproperties or an element named `name` for instance. having all the elements in there as `tag` make it hard to parse or find like @alfredo-aguirre mentions.

---

*update again*  https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html

Here is a snippet for using the DOM (document object model)

https://repl.it/@mark_boyle_sp/StimulatingStimulatingTypes

Comment: wow, thank you very much, Is there a way i can pass it a value like the hostname "WebServerA" and then for it to give me the host-ip?

Comment: Hey thanks, i just tried this but it didn't seem to work, not sure where i'm messing up the syntax:                                                                   for host in root.iterfind(".//HostProperties/tag/name/[@host-fqdn='WebServerA.internal']"):
    print vuln.text

Comment: that would be `./HostProperties/tag[@name='host-fqdn']` but it will parse the fqdn only from the xml and iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

With the code posted you'd have to iterate over all the children until you find the tag you need.

Instead of doing that you can get the parser to access directly the attribute you need:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# XML payload redacted:
xml_text = "<xml>...</xml>"
root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
for tag in root.findall("./HostProperties/tag[@name='host-ip']"):
    print(tag.text)
```